# How can I achieve converting a list to 2d list this using itertools or collections with high performance

Tags: python, list, collections, python-itertools

By simply technique i can think of, I am converting a list to 2d list, However is it possible to achievie this with higher performance either by `itertools` or `collections`?

```
n = 2
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 'e']
for i in  range(0, len(lst), n):
    print lst[i:i+n]
```

Expected output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 2], ['e']]
```

Comment: You mean you wanted to produce sub lists of every 2 values?

Comment: Use `xrange` for a more efficient generator.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I am using a 2d list for passing the list of image paths to `QListview` however no intentions for what you have voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> thing = [lst[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(lst),n)]
>>> thing
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 2], ['e']]
```

Using a list comprehension